# How do I get rid of the "Configure Blocks" link above my menus?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I know the answer to this will be obvious (and probably embarrassing), but the link started appearing on my new development site, and I want to turn it off to do some styling.  The link only appears above menus and I cannot find a setting in a relevant module to turn it off. This problem is at the annoying stage for me, but could become an obsession if I..don't....squash.....this......nasty..........bug!

Does anyone know what controls this?  :)

Comment: Why disbaling contextual links? Visitors won't see this... And it's very usefull and fast to change content / menus / blocks ... I would suggest to keep it enabled :)

Comment: I'm doing some styling and don't want the link affecting the page while I am doing so.

Comment: I understand, but why not use 2 different browsers? IE & Chrome for example. On one you don't log in, so you don't see the contextual links. That would be my sollution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those links come from the core "Contextual links" module; you should be able to pop to `http://mysite.com/admin/modules`, disable the module and see the links disappear :)

A bit of extra info on Contextual Links:

http://drupal7ish.blogspot.com/2011/06/contextual-links.html

Comment: Check mark for providing additional information link!

Comment: Wait a minute, my Contextual Filters module was off and I am getting these links?????

Comment: That's odd maybe they're coming from another module, any chance you can take a screenshot and add it to your question? That might help identify where they're coming from!

Comment: Nope, it gets weirder... When I turn on Contextual Filters, the Configure Block links disappear, when I disable it, they reappear!  I love when things work the way they are supposed to!!!

Comment: Wow that's pretty incredible! I'd try disabling the module, then visiting the 'Uninstall' tab in modules and actually un-installing it...maybe then it'll bugger off

Answer (score 2):

The Contextual Links core module controls these.  Just turn that off and you're laughing!